# How to make Brew show the size of the formula before installing it?

Tags: macos, package, homebrew

I'm looking for a way to make `brew` show the size of a formula without installing it. I've tried various options to `brew info` and `brew install`, but neither let me view the size of the formula.

However, when installing a formula, its size is shown as part of the output.

Any ideas?

```
nlykkei-mbp:Projects nlykkei$ brew info llvm
llvm: stable 8.0.1 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
Next-gen compiler infrastructure
https://llvm.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/llvm.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔
Required: libffi ✔, swig ✔
==> Requirements
Build: xcode ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

==> Analytics
install: 15,199 (30 days), 39,871 (90 days), 183,880 (365 days)
install_on_request: 11,125 (30 days), 30,095 (90 days), 140,885 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. If a formula doesn’t have a bottle (= pre-built archive) you can’t know its size without installing it.
2. If a formula has a bottle, you need to download it to know its compressed size

I’m skipping the first issue because it has no solution for your case. Regarding the second one, we can get the URL of a bottle using Homebrew’s JSON API and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ brew info --json=v1 llvm | jq --raw-output '.[0].bottle.stable.files.big_sur.url'
https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/llvm/blobs/sha256:ff9a71b7b35ecb6c1dfcfe40152b00f4777a3f4a10dcf5cc41044458b02c99cd
```

Note: because this URL is very long, I’m truncating it in the commands below so they are easier to read.

We can `curl` this URL to know the compressed size. Note that since April 2021, ghcr.io require authentification, but [using a dummy token works](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/11066). We use `-I` to perform a `HEAD` request and get the response headers without its body (`-L` = follow redirects; `-s` don’t show progress).

```
$ curl -Ls -I -H 'Authorization: Bearer QQ==' https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/... | grep -i content-length
content-length: 474762229
```

The gzip-compressed size of this formula is 474,762,229 bytes, i.e. ~474MiB.

gzip’d archives don’t contain their final size; we *must* uncompress them to know it.

We can stream the archive through `gunzip` and get its size without storing anything on the disk:

```
$ curl -Ls -H 'Authorization: Bearer QQ==' https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/... | gunzip - | wc -c
1695293440
```

The uncompressed `llvm` formula weights 1,695,293,440 bytes, i.e. ~1.7GiB.

Unfortunately this can take some time depending on your connection and the bottle’s size.

One-liner:

```
brew info --json=v1 llvm | jq -r '.[0].bottle.stable.files.big_sur.url' | xargs curl -Ls -H 'Authorization: Bearer QQ==' | gunzip - | wc -c
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I personally think the formula size should be added as meta data to a formula. By "pre-built archive", you mean a .tar archive containing executable files and dependencies (or the result of running `make` on the source code)?

Comment: @Shuzheng the "pre-built archive" is generated a bit like "brew install llvm" from source (`make`, etc) then tar/gz the resulting `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1` directory.

Comment: "@bfontaine" - by "generated a bit like `brew install llvm` from source", you mean how other formulae without bottles are installed on the system, i.e. `brew` downloads the source files and runs `make` on them? Is there an option to force `brew` to install from source instead of from bottle?

Comment: Yes! You can run `brew install --from-source` (or `-s` for short).

Comment: Thanks again. But not all Brew formulae will be available as source, right? Can formula also be bottle-only, or is it a requirement that source always be available through Brew (Sorry, I'm new to Brew)?

Comment: It’s a requirement that source must always be available (and under an open-source licence). Bottles are here only to save you compilation time but building from source or from the bottle should have the same result.

Comment: They added authentication to access downloads... any idea where to get credentials from without spending a day digging in brew code?

Comment: @RobM Thanks for the heads up! I updated the answer; the TL;DR is you have to add `-H 'Authorization: Bearer QQ=='` to your `curl` calls.

Comment: Excellent - maybe you can add some more info like `ghcr.io` is the Github Packages Website or the `curl` flags. I do not understand why you use once `I` flag and then finally switch to `L`. Probably `L` which is location includes `I` - include Response Headers. As I have a Mac Mini, I use in `jq` `bottle.stable.files.arm64_monterey.url`. Finally, `r` in jq means raw-output, no json but text.

Comment: @Timo thanks for the feedback; I clarified the answer.